# How to use Spring Collections with Spring Boot using STS?

Tags: collections, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I want to Implement Spring Collections in Spring MVC using Spring Boot.

How to use the following Spring Collection with Spring Boot 1.2.5

**appConfig.xml**

```
<bean id="appConfig" class="com.xyz.common.AppConfig">
    <!-- java.util.List -->
    <property name="lists">
        <list>
        </list>
    </property>
    <!-- java.util.Set -->
    <property name="sets">
        <set>
        </set>
    </property>
    <!-- java.util.Map -->
    <property name="maps">
        <map>
        </map>
    </property>
    <!-- java.util.Properties -->
    <property name="pros">
        <props>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
public class AppConfig 
{
    private List<Object> lists;
    private Set<Object> sets;
    private Map<Object, Object> maps;
    private Properties pros;

    //...

    getter 
    setter
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: I'm also not quite sure what it is you are asking.

Comment: Spring collection ie <list> <map>...................how to use them in spring boot applications ?????